# capture object tag children events using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The predicament i am facing is as follows,
i wish to redirect the user to an other page once he clicks on the link which is present in the page embedded using an object tag..this works fine in chrome and ff where the entire page is redirected to the new location whereas in ie , only the object frame(is it a frame in the first place??) is redirected...

to circumvent this i tried  using an  anchor tag with the href set to javascript:void(0) and the click event captured using jquery

```
<body>
    <div id='gridDude'>
        <a id='titleDude'   href='javascript:void(0)' myHref='yabadabadoo.com'>test</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#gridDude').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
                 alert("CLICKED");
                 window.parent.location = $(this).attr('myHref');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

this approach seems to work for an iframe but fails when i use the object tag though...
so i am pretty sure the dom structure might be quite different for an object tag... I am unable to use an iframe though as flickering is observed...(whenever the mouse is moved...)

Comment: I don't quite understand something you need the frame and the new page is loaded into the frame or you don't need the frame for load a new page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com"
```

this redirect the entire window

Answer (score 0):

changing the doctype to ensure ie works in standard mode kinda fixed it....